# Perl - Removing all special characters except a few

Tags: regex, perl

So i came across a Perl regex "term" which allows you to remove all punctuation. Here is the code:

```
$string =~ s/[[:punct:]]//g;.
```

However this proceeds to remove all special characters. Is there a way that particular regex expression can be modified so that for example, it removes all special characters except hyphens. As i stated on my previous question with Perl, i am new to the language, thus obvious things don't come obvious to me. Thanks for all the help :_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like below to remove all the punctuations except hyphen,

```
$string =~ s/(?!-)[[:punct:]]//g;
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pQ0tL4/3)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = "foo;\"-bar'.,...*(){}[]----";
$string =~ s/(?!-)[[:punct:]]//g;
print "$string\n";
```

Output:

```
foo-bar----
```

Comment: You don't need an atomic group around the pattern. `(?!-)[[:punct:]]` is enough.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I will ask it as another question and mark this as solved. Thanks :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I don't know what question you have answered, but it clearly isn't the problem that the OP has

Comment: op wants to remove all the punctuations except the hyphens. That's what i understand. And also i ask him to edit or ask a new question. He choose the second option.

Comment: @Avinash Raj answered the question i had. The other question i had was different than what i had posted in the OP :)

Comment: When it comes with entity it will remove the semicolon. for example : foo&#x2002; in this case it will remove the semicolon also.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - How would i modify this so that it removes everything except hyphens and apostrophes?

Comment: Ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use unicode property:

```
$string =~ s/[^-\PP]+//g;
```